# 2014 MacBook Pro Retina Failed Boot Camp Install, Loading Screens During Boot

Tags: bootcamp, macbook-pro, windows

My girlfriend has a 2014 MacBook Pro Retina that we tried to install Windows 7 on through BootCamp. The install failed (I don't remember how... It actually got partway through the install), and since then it looks like there are loading screens (Similar to the "Windows is loading..." screen on the windows 7 install media, before you see the blue background with the installer) during boot.

We have disabled bootcamp and removed the space set aside for windows with the OS X disk manager. Does anyone know what this is, and how we can stop it happening?

Comment: and you used the bootcamp assistant from you Utility folder ?

Comment: and followed the instructions from here http://support.apple.com/kb/PH18825

Comment: and do not mess around with disk partitions. and have a clean copy (ISO) of the Win7 on USB.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the information you gave I can't really guess why, but your Windows install failed.
I would suggest you try again, making sure you carefully follow the instructions in Apple's [Boot Camp manual](http://manuals.info.apple.com/MANUALS/1000/MA1636/en_US/boot_camp_install-setup_10.8.pdf) step by step.

Be sure to back up your data before doing so.